# Traer una serie de datos y guardarlos en un array

Tags: c#

Debo traer los nombres del PDF para que los busque en una carpeta y ya luego los una en un solo documento pero no me esta trayendo los nombres

```
public string[] GetFiles()
{
    List<string> listTemp = new List<string>();

    string pathBase = @"C:\Users\bodega\Documents\Manifiestos";

    List<string> trasteList = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                        .Select(row => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                                        .ToList();

    foreach(string traste in trasteList)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathBase, traste);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*.pdf");

        List<string> filesNames = files.Select(x=> Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();

        listTemp.AddRange(filesNames);
    }

    return listTemp.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendi bien tu codigo deberia ser algo como esto

```
public string[] GetFiles()
{
    List<string> listTemp = new List<string>();

    string pathBase = @"C:\Users\bodega\Documents\Manifiestos";

    List<string> trasteList = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                                        .Select(row => row.Cells[1].Value.ToString())
                                        .ToList();

    foreach(string traste in trasteList)
    {
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(pathBase, traste);
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(fullPath, "*.pdf");

        List<string> filesNames = files.Select(x=> Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();

        listTemp.AddRange(filesNames);
    }

    return listTemp.ToArray();
}
```

La iteracion que realizas del `DataGridView` se reduce a una query `linq` que recuera los valores de `traste` para que despues puedas iteralos y obtener los archivos que unido al `pathBase` forman la ruta donde tomar los `pdf` que contenga

Usa la ayuda de `Directory.GetFiles()` para obtener la lista con un dato simple, y la de `Path.Combine()` y `Path.GetFileName()` para trabajar con la ruta completa que se obtiene

Comment: Muchas gracias funciona bien pero el no coje los archivos porque terminan en .PDF osea que me dice que no los encuentra pero en el arreglo si estan solo que debe ser (nombre + ".PDF").

Comment: no entendi, que cosa tiene que ser nombre + ".PDF" ? lo que etendi recuperas son los pdf de una carpeta, la cual armas en base a una ruta base mas uan parte que obtienes del datagridview

Comment: El programa funciona de la siguiente manera, en un carpeta tengo unos PDF y debo cojer unos en especifico y unirlos en un solo documento por eso debo tener el nombre completo para luego concatenarlos en un solo documento PDF

Comment: Esos pdf especificos donde lo define ?

Comment: C:\Users\bodega\Documents\Manifiestos

Comment: en esa ruta estan los pdf, pero si usas el `Directory.GetFiles()` te traera todos, como sabes cuales necesitas?

Comment: Tengo una consulta donde lleno un DataGrid con los PDF que debo imprimir, de esa forma traigo especificamente los archivos al LIST

Comment: entonces en el grid tienes lo nombres de los archivos, la verdad te has explicado bastante mal, recomendaria crees una nueva pregunta explicando que es lo que estas queriendo armar, pero explica claro que tienes en la lista

Comment: no edites esta pregunta, edita la otra que has creado que aun no tiene respuesta

Comment: OK, ya empece esa nueva pregunta